# Process ID is always 0 in linux, Is it valid?

Tags: c, linux, pid

My program finds the pid in Linux. But it’s always returning 0. Is it supposed to be like this? I used `gcc`. Is it valid? When will I get process IDs without 0? Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
        pid_t pid;

       /* get the process id */
        if ((pid = getpid()) < 0)
                perror(" unable to get pid");
        else
                printf(" The process id is %d", pid);
        return (0);
}
```

So after compiling the program it always prints in the Terminal “The process id is: 0”.

Comment: Remove the check. `getpid` can't fail. Also please print it as a long long int (`pid_t` is 64 bit).

Comment: Very strange. Could you post the output of strace (i.e. run `strace ./your-program`)?

Comment: I've never seen a system with 64-bit `pid_t`, but you should in principle cast pids to `intmax_t` and print them with `%jd` since there's no format specifically for `pid_t`.

Comment: I smell fake code. I suspect you wrote: `if (pid = getpid() < 0)`. If so, JakeGould's deleted answer is actually very close to being right.

Comment: the code shown works for me on Ubuntu 12.04 printing the correct pid each time (sizeof pid_t is 4, uname -m shows x86_64 so this is 64-bit Linux)

Comment: I just removed the if else part and just set pid = getpid(); as someone said getpid() never fails so there isnt any necessity to check it. Now it works. Dont know how. It shows pid properly. Thanks.